# How to set a variable with the value of a pattern found in a file

Tags: regex, powershell

How can I set a variable with the value of a found pattern in a file.

For example :

```
$Pattern = "\$LastChangedRevision\: [0-9]* \$" <#svn keyword#>
```

In my file :

```
Version = 1.$LastChangedRevision: 123 $.
```

I want to put the "123" in a variable. I've tried with a `Select-String` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this with the `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
$yourVariable = (Select-String -path 'path_to_your_file' -Pattern 'LastChangedRevision: (\d+)').Matches.Groups[1].Value
```